# What' software can I use to simulate a solar power system?

Tags: linux, electronics

I'm designing my first solar power system and it would be great to build a model to test all my math before buying parts.

Is there a circuit simulator that includes things like solar panels, water pumps, solar controllers, etc, and preferably that runs on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 1d thermodynamic cycle evaluation software in linux.  A software that can consider transients would be desireable to account for variable sun thermo-inputs and look at capacitances need in your system.

One linux example, I see is a python system called: MCycle: A Python package for 1D sizing and analysis of thermodynamic power cycles.  Available from github. Looks like a text based system; not gui.  I have no experience with this but superficially looks useful.

I use an old windows gui thermo-analysis software called "cyclepad".  Ref: https://www.qrg.northwestern.edu/software/cyclepad/cyclesof.htm.  Has gui build network capability. Runs fine in wine on openSUSE linux.  This has many heat input modules but I dont know if solar input is available.